# How to add gridview rows to a datatable?

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

I have a gridview which will contain some 'n' number of rows.... Now i want to add all rows of  the gridview to a datatable which will be used for bulkcopy operation...

I have found this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/GridView_To_DataTable.aspx

But i want all columns of my gridview to be added to the datarow of the datatable
[Grid http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/4044/gridp.jpg](http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/4044/gridp.jpg)

I want to convert gridview to datatable on submit.... Any suggestion...

**EDIT:**

Answer below works and i have found an answer too...

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EmpId", typeof(Int64)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FromDate", typeof(DateTime)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ToDate", typeof(DateTime)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DaysPresent", typeof(double)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("OpeningAdvance", typeof(double)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AdvanceDeducted", typeof(double)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RemainingAdvance", typeof(double)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SalaryGiven", typeof(double)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CreatedDate", typeof(DateTime)));

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gridEmployee.Rows) 
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["EmpId"] = Convert.ToInt64(((HiddenField)row.Cells[0].FindControl("HiddenId")).Value);
            dr["FromDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(GetMonthNumberFromAbbreviation(fromdate[1].ToString()) + '/' + fromdate[0].ToString() + '/' + fromdate[2].ToString());
            dr["ToDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(GetMonthNumberFromAbbreviation(todate[1].ToString()) + '/' + todate[0].ToString() + '/' + todate[2].ToString());
            dr["DaysPresent"] = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)row.Cells[3].FindControl("TxtDaysPresent")).Text);
            dr["OpeningAdvance"] = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)row.Cells[4].FindControl("txtOpeningAdv")).Text);
            dr["AdvanceDeducted"] = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)row.Cells[5].FindControl("TxtAdvanceDeducted")).Text);
            dr["RemainingAdvance"] = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)row.Cells[6].FindControl("TxtClosingAdvance")).Text);
            dr["SalaryGiven"] = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)row.Cells[7].FindControl("TxtSalary")).Text);
            dr["CreatedDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
    SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString);
    sbc.DestinationTableName = "SalaryDetails";
    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("EmpId", "EmpId");
    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("FromDate", "FromDate");
    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("ToDate", "ToDate");
    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("DaysPresent", "DaysPresent");
    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("OpeningAdvance", "OpeningAdvance");
    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("AdvanceDeducted", "AdvanceDeducted");
    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("RemainingAdvance", "RemainingAdvance");
    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("SalaryGiven", "SalaryGiven");
    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("CreatedDate", "CreatedDate");
    sbc.WriteToServer(dt);
    sbc.Close();
```

Comment: How did you get the data in first place? From a DataTable?

Comment: @madatanic but i ll get only the label datas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can traverse datagrid row by row and make a comma separated file. then use Bulk insert or bcp for inserting data to db.

**Another Solution**

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();    
    for (int j = 0; j < grdList.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        DataRow dr;
        GridViewRow row = grdList.Rows[j];
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            dr[i] = row.Cells[i].Text;
        }

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(targetConnStr);
sbc.DestinationTableName = "yourDestinationTable";
sbc.WriteToServer(dt);
sbc.Close();
```

Comment: @masoud foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' because 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: @masoud i found `foreach (GridViewRow row in yourGridView.Rows)`

Comment: @masoud `cannot find column 0`... Look at my gridview it has labels and textboxes...

Comment: you must do like this :

dr[i] = ((TextBox)(row.FindControl("textBoxID"))).Text;

Comment: you must know the structure of your grid for getting data from it.