# Save data in bulk

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a window having multiple tabs. Each tab having different grids. I want to save all changes on any tab on any grid in bulk. I mean I have one save button which will save all changes in any grid on any tab.

I think DataTables will work fine here.

Can you suggest me that it is good to use DataTables to ADD/Edit data and save data in bulk using these DataTables OR is there any better way to achieve this.

My DAL is generated from LLBLGen Pro (ORM) but you are open to suggest me a solution.

Thanks.

Edit: I am using Telerik controls so I can get all data in DataTable like

```
DataTable dtProducts = this.radGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see this :

[How to add gridview rows to a datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332098/how-to-add-gridview-rows-to-a-datatable)

maybe it is useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for this link. In fact I already have used this technique to save data using DataTables I just wanted to know that is there any better approach of this?