# Add Gridview Rows

Tags: vb.net, gridview, oracle10g, row

While referencing [How to add gridview rows to a datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332098/how-to-add-gridview-rows-to-a-datatable), I have tried to create a gridview based on an array.

So far my array [ **email_list** ] has strings where each index has **3 strings delimited by |**.

**Example:**

Index1:  `1231|Apple Company|apple@yahoo.com`

Index2:  `141411|KFC|eatChicken@yahoo.com`

**To separate the strings I do the following [it does work]**

```
 Dim strarray2() As String = email_list(i).Split("|"c)

  For Each str2 In strarray2
    Dim r As String = ""
    r = strarray2(y)
    y = y + 1
  Next

 ID = strarray2(0)
 company = strarray2(1)
 email = strarray2(2)
```

**What I want:**

I want to fill my gridview everytime I loop through the email_list array.

**Issue:**

As of right now, the strings get separated into 3 variables: `ID, company, email` and I debugged the strings and they do in fact work.

However; after the values are added to the gridview the gridview doesn't populate[aka doesn't show up on page]. This tells me that the way I am adding the new rows is wrong.

I tried doing:

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In DisplaySup.Rows
   If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
```

outside my coding but since there is no rows currently made, all of my coding inside doesn't execute so I took it out.

Any suggestions on how to modify my following coding?

**VB.NET**

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

   dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ID", GetType(String)))
   dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Company Name", GetType(String)))
   dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Email", GetType(String)))

        For i As Integer = 0 To email_list.Length - 2

            Dim y As Integer = 0
            Dim strarray2() As String = email_list(i).Split("|"c)

            For Each str2 In strarray2
                Dim r As String = ""
                r = strarray2(y)
                y = y + 1
            Next

            ID = strarray2(0)
            company = strarray2(1)
            email = strarray2(2)

            'ADD ONE ROW AT A TIME [my logic of what I want]
            Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
            dr("ID") = Convert.ToString(ID)
            dr("Company Name") = Convert.ToString(company)
            dr("Email") = Convert.ToString(email)
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)

      Next
```

**HTML:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="DisplaySup" runat="server" align="center" 
Width="99%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" DataKeyNames="ID" 
cssClass="grid_padding4" Font-Size="XX-Small">
   <Columns>

       <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID"> 
       <ItemStyle cssClass="grid_padding" width="15px"/>
       </asp:BoundField>

       <asp:BoundField DataField="company" HeaderText="Company Name" > 
       <ItemStyle cssClass="grid_padding" width="125px"/>
       </asp:BoundField>

       <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Owner Email" > 
       <ItemStyle cssClass="grid_padding" width="50px"/>
       </asp:BoundField>

    </Columns>

    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#BDBDAE" Font-Underline="False" 
       CssClass="linkNoUnderline" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#99CCFF" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: The foreach loop `For Each str2 In strarray2 ... Next` seems to have no purpose. What are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: Once you have filled the datatable with your rows, do you bind the datatable to your gridview? IE: grid.DataSource=dt and grd,DataBind()

Comment: @Namrehs the str2 in strarray2 separates the string inside each delimiter to it's own variable. Each string within the delimiter should be in it's own column in the gridview. aka column 1 = Id, column 2 = company, column 3 = email

Comment: @Steve no I didn't add that coding. I just did and it says that my DataField doesn't exist inside gridview. not sure why. Should my dt " " or dr " " match the DataField?

Comment: @Namrehs my str2 in strarray2 is working. That isn't the issue. It is binding the `ID, company and email` variables to the gridview

Comment: @Namrehs the strarray2(0) ..etc gets each part of the string and my for loop resets it. So it works [I have used this many times and it works after debugging]

Comment: @Steve I removed all DataField and DataKeyNames from gridview. The grid now shows after VB.net runs. However, the gridview is empty

Comment: @Namrehs this is how the coding works. My `email_list` array gets the `index(0)` for instance. `index(0`) has a delimited string. the `strarray2 ` splits the 3 values for `Index(0)` and saves them in their own variables. Therefore, `ID = '1213'` , `company = 'Apple Company'` and `email = 'apple@yahoo.com'.` Like I said that isn't the issue of my question. My question is sending those 3 new variables into the grid. Once they are in the grid my loop is initiated again and now I am in email_list Index(1). You understand?

Comment: @Namrehs the for loop isn't the issue. IT WORKS. I just can't figure out how to make a new row in the gridview

Comment: @Namrehs if you would like you can test my example however; I have been using this setup a lot and have made various pages that work. I have no issues...errors... and etc coming from my strings :(

Comment: I added the coding from the bottom to the top now so you can see how I am getting the strings [I am confused that maybe you are missing that coding] @Namrehs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created the `DataTable` that is OK but have you assigned it to the `GridView`? Check all the comments in CAPITALS in code

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ID", GetType(String)))

'YOUR DATACOUMN NAME IN DATATABLE  AND  DATAFIELD OF BOUNDFIELD IN GRIDVIEW MUST MATCH
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("company", GetType(String)))
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("email", GetType(String)))

For i As Integer = 0 To email_list.Length - 2' SHOULD IT NOT BE email_list.Length - 1, IF LAST ONE IS NOT BLANK
    Dim y As Integer = 0
    Dim strarray2() As String = email_list(i).Split("|"c)

    'AS Namrehs POINTED IN COMMENTS, NO YOU REALLY DON'T NEED THAT "For Each str2 In strarray2" LOOP

    ID = strarray2(0)
    company = strarray2(1)
    email = strarray2(2)

    'ADD ONE ROW AT A TIME [my logic of what I want]
    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
    dr("ID") = Convert.ToString(ID)
    dr("company") = Convert.ToString(company)
    dr("email") = Convert.ToString(email)
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
Next

'HERE YOU ALSO HAVE TO ASSIGN AND BIND IT TO THE GRIDVIEW
DisplaySup.DataSource = dt
DisplaySup.DataBind()
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining over the `"company"` string inside the `columns.Add`. I wasn't completely sure what they related to. My issue was in fact that they were not the same as my Datafields. 

Also, Namrehs showed me in private chat about being able to remove the strarray2 loop. I was informed in the past that I can do it that way and thus; when he began explaining I didn't see why my coding was unneeded [hence my down grade of post].

Comment: Therefore, I do thank you for explaining that. This is the first time that I haven't filled a gridview all at once without a Dataset. I also attempted putting DataSource and Databind inside the for loop [good to know it is suppose to be on the outside]. Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome, as you were already splitting the string into array using `Dim strarray2() As String = email_list(i).Split("|"c)` so that loop was not needed.

Comment: Yes I see that now. I now know that the process that I was taught before was redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are bothering with the datatable. Here is some code to display an array in an unbound DataGridView (dgv1.) It doesn't change the array contents so perhaps you were expecting to use the datatable for updates?

```
Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    ' overhead for my testing
    Dim sData() As String = {"1231|Apple Company|apple@yahoo.com", "141411|KFC|eatChicken@yahoo.com"}
    dgv1.DataSource = Nothing

    ' could be done in designer one time
    dgv1.Columns.Clear()
    dgv1.Columns.Add("ID", "ID")
    dgv1.Columns.Add("Company", "Company")
    dgv1.Columns.Add("URL", "URL")

    For Each s As String In sData
        dgv1.Rows.Add(s.Split("|"))
    Next
    dgv1.AutoResizeColumns()
    dgv1.ClearSelection()
End Sub
```